# Implicit cast of functional interface

Tags: java, functional-programming

I want to implicitly cast my own interface implementation to a Java8 function.

My code:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@FunctionalInterface
interface StringChanger {
    String change(String o);
}

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("hello", "world")
                .map(new StringChanger() {

                    @Override
                    public String change(String o) {
                        return o.trim();
                    }
                })
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Why does the cast not work?

I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method map(Function<? super String,? extends R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Trimmer)

    at A.main(A.java:13)
```

Comment: *"my own interface implementation"* makes no sense. An interface is not an implementation by essence. Why do you want to have `StringChanger` instead of `UnaryOperator<String>` and why does it matter?

Comment: Wow you completely changed the question, invalidating all the current answers. This is not cool and I think it should be rollbacked. Mena and chengpohi even had to delete their answers as a result of this, so they literally lost their time trying to help you!

Comment: The peer pressure made me revert my changes to this (often downvoted) question. The updated version is moved to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35866449/476791 . @Tunaki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `map` method doesn't expect a `StringChanger` implementation. It expects a `Function` implementation.

What you can do is create an implementation of your `StringChanger` interface, and pass a method reference of your implementation to `map` :

```
 StringChanger sc = new StringChanger() {
     @Override
     public String change(String o) {
         return o.trim();
     }
 };
 Stream.of("hello", "world")
       .map(sc::change)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

EDIT:

In order to assign an implementation of one functional interface to a different functional interface reference, you can assign a method reference of the source functional interface's method :

```
    MyConsumer i3 = i::accept;
    IntConsumer i4 = i2::doSomething;
```

Comment: @slartidan Casting is not possible since these functional interfaces don't belong to the same type hierarchy. If `MyConsumer` was a sub-interface of `IntConsumer`, you could have cast a `MyConsumer` instance to `IntConsumer`.