# How to change the type of a function reference?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Java8 lets me use a method declaration as implementation of any of my interfaces, as long as it only contains one method.

However once it is defined, the type cannot be changed.

My code:

```
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;

public class A {

    interface MyConsumer {
        void doSomething(int i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntConsumer i = A::consume;
        MyConsumer i2 = A::consume;

        IntConsumer i3 = (IntConsumer) i2; // ClassCastException
        MyConsumer i4 = (MyConsumer) i; // ClassCastException

        IntConsumer i5 = i2; // does not compile
        MyConsumer i6 = i; // does not compile

        IntConsumer i7 = i2::doSomething; // workaround, as suggested by @Eran http://stackoverflow.com/a/35846001/476791
        MyConsumer i8 = i::accept;

        Object i9 = A::consume; // does not compile
        Object i10 = (IntConsumer) A::consume; // works
        Object i11 = (MyConsumer) A::consume; // works
        Object i12 = (MyConsumer) (IntConsumer) A::consume; // does not work
    }

    static void consume(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Note: if you *inline* some of the variables, then some of the non-working examples suddenly start to work.

My thoughts in detail:

1. if `IntConsumer i = A::consume` is valid, then `A::consume` has to `implement IntConsumer`
2. if `MyConsumer i2 = A::consume` is valid, then `A::consume` has to `implement MyConsumer`
3. if `A::consume` implements **both**, `IntConsumer` and `MyConsumer`, then casting should be possible

Is there another way to "cast" or "change" the type of the consumer afterwards?

Comment: I would suggest you to read about `Functional Interface` and `method reference`. What you are seeing is not plain inheritance. Those implements logic don't apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A::consume` has no inherent type.  When it appears in a context in which it is being used or assigned to a functional interface type, the compiler will create an object of *that type* implemented using `A::consume`.

Once you have that, you have an object of that specific functional interface type.  It's not a method; it's a perfectly normal object.  Java objects can't pretend to be other types their real type doesn't implement or extend.

So once you have an `IntConsumer`, you can't cast it to a `MyConsumer`.  You can use it to get a method reference that can then become a *new* `MyConsumer`, but that one object will always be just an `IntConsumer`, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another way to "cast" or "change" the type of the consumer afterwards?

You can't change the actual type of an object(1).  You can cast a primitive, and you can cast a reference to another type suitable for the object referenced.

What you can do is wrap the instance with the type you want.

```
MyConsumer mc = ((IntConsumer) A::consume)::accept;
```

(1) you can hack the class pointer in the object header, but this is highly unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: @slartidan this is not a dynamic cast, it used by the compiler for type inference.  `A::consume` has inherent no type. `Object o = A::consume` will not compile.